# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1: Where is the package org.springframework.bind?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE had several classes in `org.springframework.boot.bind`, especially `RelaxedPropertyResolver`. However, `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.0.0.M1/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot` doesn't contain the subdirectory `bind` anymore

`RelaxedPropertyResolver` is used e.g. in `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration` both in `1.3.0.RELEASE` and in the current `2.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: This has already been taken care of in snapshots last night

Comment: Though spring-cloud-netflix 1.3.0 is not compatible with spring boot 2.0.0.x. The correct version is 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @spencergibb Looking at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java#L38 you still can find the imported class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver. Can you please clarify regarding my misunderstanding.

Comment: 2.0.0 is on the 2.0.x branch, not master.

Comment: @spencergibb, seems like current version 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT of Spring Boot is not compatible with Spring Cloud Consul v1.2.x - do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it's compatible with the 2.0.x branch