# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have updated my dependecies like you said in your comment and i have this now :

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.o2xp.ats.accountManager.test.App.main(App.java:42) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'httpPutFormContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1262) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:234) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:182) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:177) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:241) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:228) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:182) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:67) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.java:29) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration.httpPutFormContentFilter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:149) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0610338.CGLIB$httpPutFormContentFilter$1(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0610338$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3e6bfe4d.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:359) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d0610338.httpPutFormContentFilter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:155) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.RC2.jar:5.0.0.RC2]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

And ther is my new pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>   
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <groupId>com.o2xp</groupId>
  <artifactId>ats-impl</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ats-impl</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhipster</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
  <modules>
    <module>ats-application-context</module>
    <module>ats-notice-manager</module>
    <module>ats-common</module>
    <module>ats-accountManager</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

i have to precise that i never used jackson and it was working verry well. Maybe it's cause auf spring 5 ?

Comment: Seems like this class has been removed from SpringBoot 2.x but some dependencies require SpringBoot 1.x. If you don't require any specific feature of SpringBoot 2, please specify the 1.5.3 version in the POM instead of LATEST.

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031949/spring-boot-2-0-0-m1-where-is-the-package-org-springframework-bind

Comment: Using LATEST is a very bad idea to manage your dependencies. Use an explicit version.

Comment: @AlexRoig thw it worked but i have an other error that i never had before :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig it will be solved by adding the corresponding dependency but i never used jackson before and it was working perfectly can you explain why ?

Comment: Where on earth is Spring 5 coming from?! As stated don't use LATEST you probably overriding/messing with dependencies in one of your other modules, don't. You want to use Spring Boot then let boot manage the dependencies for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum i removed all the latest !

Comment: In this one but you have 4 child projects. Also make sure you don't have mixed versions of spring boot, have a `spring.version` property etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah thx i've found in an other child a redefinition of spring dependency ! I've some thing now i can't launch the app two times in a raw it says that the local host 8080 is already in use i have to close eclipse and launch again maybe you know why ?

Comment: Because you cannot have 2 processes on the same port.

Comment: and you know how to stop or kill the process automatically after executing the app ?

Comment: What is the original problem statement here?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Try to use the latest `com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind`.
I upgraded it to `2.9.4` and it works now.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i was trying to use jackson-databind 2.7.1 with spboot 2.0.2 in a kotlin project and had the same problem, upgrading to 2.9.4 as you suggested solved the problem, thanks :-)

Comment: for people using aws-sdk, exclude `<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>` and add newer version as in above answer

Comment: I am getting the issue in 2.10.0 jackson since I am trying to upgrade to 2.10.0. Also, my internal dependencies are using lower versions of jackson.

Comment: You may also need 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @prayagupd do you mean delete the  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> line?

Answer (score 15):

Use all the jackson dependencies(databind,core, annotations, scala(if you are using spark and scala)) with the same version.. and upgrade the versions to the latest releases..

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>

        </dependency>
```

Note: Use Scala dependency only if you are working with scala. Otherwise it is not needed.

Comment: It would be better answered if you provide some XML code with proper maven dependencies versions...

Comment: I was getting a similar error and this fix worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I also have the same error. I have updated the jackson library version and error has gone.

```
<!-- Jackson to convert Java object to Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and also check your data classes that have you created getters and setters for all the properties.

Answer (score 3):

If issue remains even after updating dependency version, then delete everything present under
 C:\Users\[your_username]\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml

And, make sure following dependencies are present:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/
worked for me on linux

Answer (score 1):

Replace the dependency in the POM.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

By the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: It would add clarity if you explained why updating this dependency would fix the issue.

Comment: Yes Dolan, The issue was solved replacing the dependency in POM file, Im using Spring MVC v. 5.0.6.RELEASE, the jackson.core library doesnt has a required method to use the last version of Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

Worked by lowering the spring boot starter parent to 1.5.13

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be solved in latest versions of Spring Boot. If you are still facing it, there is a strong possibility that same Jackson artifacts are defined in other libraries you use, thereby transitively causing conflicts in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced the same issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
```

with dependencies like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

To fix it you can use these versions of dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

or:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got 2 main differences that caused issues when I compared my working configuration dependency tree with new configuration dependency tree for jackson..
To get Dependency tree::(look for differences and get to solution)
mvn dependency:tree

What worked for me after comparing differences::

1. updated child dependency of jackson-bind -> jackson-core and jackson-annotations
2. Excluded jackson-module-jaxb-annotations from org.glassfish.jersey.media and included new version dependency for same.