# Spring Boot - IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]

Tags: java, spring, maven

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721409/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-parallelcapableclassloaderavailable).

***Problem***: I cloned a [demo for spring microservices](https://github.com/paulc4/microservices-demo)  (also has a [blog entry](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring#running-the-system)) and updated all the outdated jars. After `mvn clean package` I get this error

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

10628: INFO  AccountsControllerIntegrationTests - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
10628: WARN  ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
10628: INFO  AccountsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ef860c3 - dataSource() invoked
10628: INFO  AccountsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ef860c3 - dataSource = org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy@6ab7ce48
10628: INFO  AccountsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ef860c3 - System has 21 accounts
10628: ERROR PropertiesConfigurationFactory - Properties configuration failed validation
10628: ERROR PropertiesConfigurationFactory - Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'hibernate.namingStrategy': rejected value [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.java.lang.Class,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,hibernate.namingStrategy]; arguments []; default message [hibernate.namingStrategy]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'hibernate.namingStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]
10628: WARN  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jpa.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Could not bind properties to JpaProperties (prefix=spring.jpa, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'hibernate.namingStrategy': rejected value [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.java.lang.Class,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,hibernate.namingStrategy]; arguments []; default message [hibernate.namingStrategy]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'hibernate.namingStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]
10628: ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jpa.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Could not bind properties to JpaProperties (prefix=spring.jpa, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'hibernate.namingStrategy': rejected value [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.java.lang.Class,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,hibernate.namingStrategy]; arguments []; default message [hibernate.namingStrategy]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'hibernate.namingStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jpa.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Could not bind properties to JpaProperties (prefix=spring.jpa, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'hibernate.namingStrategy': rejected value [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.java.lang.Class,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,hibernate.namingStrategy]; arguments []; default message [hibernate.namingStrategy]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'hibernate.namingStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.jpa.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES': Could not bind properties to JpaProperties (prefix=spring.jpa, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'hibernate.namingStrategy': rejected value [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.java.lang.Class,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,hibernate.namingStrategy]; arguments []; default message [hibernate.namingStrategy]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'hibernate.namingStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'spring.jpa' on field 'hibernate.namingStrategy': rejected value [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]; codes [typeMismatch.spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.hibernate.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.namingStrategy,typeMismatch.java.lang.Class,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [spring.jpa.hibernate.namingStrategy,hibernate.namingStrategy]; arguments []; default message [hibernate.namingStrategy]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'hibernate.namingStrategy'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334)
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

***Dependencies*** This is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
<artifactId>microservice-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>  <!-- Name of release train -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Eureka for service registration -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>io.pivotal.microservices.services.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin> -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***Remark*** After changing the spring boot version to >1.5 I had to make some minor changes such as `@SpringBootTest(classes = AccountsMain.class)` instead of `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = AccountsMain.class)`

When I remove the `org.springframework:spring-core` dependency I get same error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259508/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-core-io-resource) (NoClassDefFoudError: KotlinDetector <- is in spring-core).

Thanks for the help

Comment: I would recommend to use the spring boot parent and let spring boot define it's main class etc.

Comment: Thanks, I took the same `.pom` as in the github repo but now I get a different error