# Spring application not working in JBOSS but works with Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss

Here is what I'm doing.

Deploying this application fails in jboss where as it deploys in tomcat and works like charm.

I'm using dynamic web application from eclipse as project source.

Exporting the project to war file and deploying in jboss server also wont work.

```
pom.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sixdee.engrafi.bl</groupId>
<artifactId>Engrafi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
    </dependency>

       <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javalite/javalite-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
        <artifactId>javalite-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </depende`enter code here`ncy>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Engrafi</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sixdee.engrafi.bl" />

</beans>
```

controller:

```
package com.sixdee.engrafi.bl;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class AnotherTest {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AnotherTest.class);
    @RequestMapping(produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,value="/ahi")
    @ResponseBody

    public String test(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("logging");
        System.out.println("Hello"); 
        String message = "{\"a\":\"b\"}";
        return message;
    }

}
```

and error in JBOSS:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
```

Comment: See if this question helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718345/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-invaliddefini

Comment: Check your dependencies with mvn dependency:tree. It is likely that there is an error with regards to scoping of the jackson artifact since it is working from within your IDE, i.e. it is provided. If everything seems normal, then you most probably have a conflict in your application's classpath and the system classpath of your jboss container. You then need to see if there is any proprietary configuration in jboss to prefer your application's classpath.

Comment: yup that worked, thanks,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the maven version jackson as shown below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```