# Application startup failed - Spring Boot when running from Docker cmd

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

Spring boot Application is build and deployed successful locally.
When I run the command from cmd it build successfully

```
$ docker build -t spring-boot-app:latest .
```

But when I run the command  :

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 spring-boot-app:latest
```

it is getting failed. And getting many errors like :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
>   defined in URL Factory method 'busJsonConverter' threw exception;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidTypeIdException Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider'

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile to your question ?

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718345/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-invaliddefini

Comment: Does the jar run on the command line ?

Comment: Dockerfile contents as below  : # Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM java:8


EXPOSE 8080

# The application's jar file
ADD target/application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar application.jar

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", "-jar", application.jar" ]

Comment: Application is build and deployed successfully locally. When build the application on linux redhat using command docker deploy.. , build is successfull. When run the application it is getting failed.