# MismatchedInputException while starting spring boot applcation

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jackson

I have a spring boot application taht was running fine.

This is how we would run:
1. Build mvn clean install
2. Do: `mvn spring-boot:run` to run the app.
3. However, in production, we would use the jar built in step 1 and run: `java -jar <jar file>`

Now, somewhere, I am not sure what we checked in, but step 3 is broken. When we run the jar file, it gives an exception:

```
2020-05-11 10:28:42.193 ERROR 25128 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/MismatchedInputException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.M3.jar!/:2.3.0.M3]
        at com.biometricServer.RestAPIServer.main(RestAPIServer.java:54) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:93) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:129) ~[demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

The app however runs perfectly fine if I run using mvn spring-boot:run.

I even tried: `mvn spring-boot:start`.
That also gives a similar exception like above.

I did a google search and suspected this could be because some of the jar files are mismatched. I tried changing some of the jar version numbers, but did not help.

Any suggestions on what the issue could be.

Note:

As suggested, I am also including the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.M3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.biometricServer</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fedRestServer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
            <version>7.49.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.jna</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.biometrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.biometrics</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.images</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.images</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.devices.NDevice</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.devices.NDevice</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.biometrics.client.NBiometricClient</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.biometrics.client.NBiometricClient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.licensing.NLicense</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.licensing.NLicense</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.io</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.io</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.media.processing</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.media.processing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.biometrics.gui</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.biometrics.gui</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.neurotec.gui</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.neurotec.gui</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ektorp/org.ektorp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ektorp</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.ektorp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId> 
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId> </exclusion> </exclusions> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>-Djna.library.path=C:\ws\MGD\Neurotec_Biometric_11_1_SDK\Bin\Win64_x64</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

In addition, when I run: `mvn spring-boot:start`, I also see the following message in addition to what we see above:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.666 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-11T11:18:20+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.M3:start (default-cli) on project demo: Could not figure out if the application has started: Failed to connect to MBean server at port 9001: Could not invoke shutdown operation: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:
[ERROR]         java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Could you please attach your pom.xml file ? It might be dependency issue.

Comment: @GaneshThorat - my bad. I added the pom xml contents.

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48566390/7458887

Comment: jackson-databind has dependencies with jackson-core and jackson-annotations. See here under Compile Dependencies: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.0

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. It worked for me.