# Error trying to start spring boot application in tomcat under linux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu-18.04, spring-rabbit

I'm developing a rest api for route optimization (solving a vehicle routing problem). My solution involves an api rest interface component for managing requests and authentication and a route procesor component that handles the route optimization part, both implemented using spring boot. Both components comunicate via rabbitmq message broker, using spring's wrapper (Spring Boot RabbiMQ), this allows me to keep a single instance of the api rest interface and process multiple requests for route optimization while allowing easy scaling of the routes procesor component. When solution is deployed in tomcat under a Windows OS it works perfectly, the problem is when I try to deploy under ubuntu server OS. It seems is unable to start because a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' **ONLY UNDER UBUNTU**.

**Here is my full stacktrace:**

> 22-Jan-2022 04:11:47.300 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: Error starting [/routes.processor]
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/routes.processor]]
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
> at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1409)
> at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:698)
> at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:223)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'formContentFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'formContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 77
> Exception Details:
> Location:
> com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer._parseDate(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/util/Date; @77: astore
> Reason:
> Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/StreamReadException' (stack map, stack[0])
> Current Frame:
> bci: @69
> flags: { }
> locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext' }
> stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParseException' }
> Stackmap Frame:
> bci: @77
> flags: { }
> locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext' }
> stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/exc/StreamReadException' }
> Bytecode:
> 0x0000000: 2bb6 0036 aa00 0000 0000 0081 0000 0003
> 0x0000010: 0000 000b 0000 007a 0000 0081 0000 0081
> 0x0000020: 0000 0034 0000 0041 0000 0081 0000 0081
> 0x0000030: 0000 0081 0000 0071 2a2b b600 13b6 0014
> 0x0000040: 2cb6 006c b02b b600 4842 a700 223a 052c
> 0x0000050: 2ab4 0002 2bb6 006f 1270 03bd 0004 b600
> 0x0000060: 71c0 002e 3a06 1906 b600 4d42 bb00 7259
> 0x0000070: 21b7 0073 b02a 2cb6 0074 c000 72b0 2a2b
> 0x0000080: 2cb6 0075 b02c 2ab4 0002 2bb6 0026 c000
> 0x0000090: 72b0
> Exception Handler Table:
> bci [69, 74] => handler: 77
> bci [69, 74] => handler: 77
> Stackmap Table:
> same_frame(@56)
> same_frame(@69)
> same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@77,Object[#371])
> append_frame(@108,Long)
> chop_frame(@117,1)
> same_frame(@126)
> same_frame(@133)

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.12</version>
            <relativePath />
        </parent>
        <groupId>cu.edu.cujae.routes.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>routes.processor</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>routes.processor</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <start-class>cu.edu.cujae.routes.application.Application</start-class>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
               <scope>test</scope>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                       <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>vrp_solver</groupId>
               <artifactId>vrp_solver</artifactId>
               <version>1.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
           <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
       </build>
 </project>
```

Comment: I think you have conflict with jackson dependencies, look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718345/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-fasterxml-jackson-databind-exc-invaliddefini
Can you have access to .m2 directory of your ubuntu server ?

Comment: @JosselinBeaud'huy thanks for the answer. I don't have a .m2 directory on ubuntu since I developed the app on a windows machine, then I packaged it as a .war and deployed it in the ubuntu server machine. As for the conflict I don't get how it can work on Windows  and not on Ubuntu. I see jsr310.JavaTimeModule in the stack trace, and I suspect It has something to do with Ubuntu's date/time but I can't figure out exactly what it is the problem.